# Synchronize code across cluster

Tags: java, synchronization, cluster-computing, hazelcast

I have an application which will eventually become a cluster behind a load balancer. The cluster (whether it's just 1 node or 10) needs to register itself with another service (via REST) once and only once when it starts up, and unregister when the final node goes offline.

That is, the first node to start should register, then any other node coming online should try to register but find that it has already been completed, and do nothing more.

When nodes go offline, they should unregister only if no other nodes are online. The last node to go offline will be responsible for unregistering.

I'm looking for tools to accomplish this. At the moment, I'm considering using Hazelcast to create a lock lease to synchronize the registration process across nodes. For unregistration, I believe Hazelcast makes all other nodes visible, so if none exist, unregister.

Are there other tools or solutions to consider which would better solve this problem?